# AngularJS dependency injection timing problems

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem related AngularJS dependency injection and timing between them. Here is my code and error

```
var module = angular.module('Demo', []);

module.factory('demo', function () {
        return {
            data: {},
        };
    });

module.provider('foo', ['demo', function(demo) {
    console.log(demo);

    this.$get = function() {
    };
}]);
```

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Demo due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: demo
```

But if I add setTimeout on last definition everything works fine, but its hacking code it shouldn't be like this.

```
var module = angular.module('Demo', []);

module.factory('demo', function () {
        return {
            data: {},
        };
    });
setTimeout(function(){
module.provider('foo', ['demo', function(demo) {
    console.log(demo);

    this.$get = function() {
    };
}]);

});
```

Here is problem on fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zcf7rb4s/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add `demo` as a dependency there because it does not yet exist. That's the way the `$injector` works. What you can do is list `demo` as a dependency in the `$get` function of the provider. That's going to be executed by the `$injector` *after* all providers have been defined.

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/92hxrfvf/):

```
<div ng-app="Demo">
    <div ng-controller="test">{{x}}</div>
</div>
```

And the definitions:

```
var module = angular.module('Demo', []);

module.factory('demo', function () {
        return {
            data: {x: 'x'},
        };
    });

module.provider('foo', function() {
    this.$get = function(demo) {
        return {
            demo: demo
        };
    };
});

module.controller('test', ['$scope', 'foo', function($scope, foo) {
    $scope.x = foo.demo.data.x;
}]);
```

The code inside the factory and provider is run at "step 1".
Then, in "step 2" AngularJS binds the controller. It first uses `$injector` to inject the dependencies (that have been previously defined in "step 1"). So in practice your `$timeout` "emulates" this behavior, that's why it works. But it's wrong, that's not the way you are supposed to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Inject into the provider like this instead:

```
module.provider('foo', function() {
    this.$get = ['demo', function(demo) {
        console.log(demo);
    }];
});
```